# How to Move Shipping information (Ship To and shipping method) below payment method

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

kindly help me with moving shipping information (Ship To and Shipping Method) below payment method. on checkout/cart/payment page in magento 2.1

Comment: which page you are talking about admin order view you mean ?

Comment: checkout/cart/payment page

Comment: I can achieve this by jquery but this script is not working. If I place this script to onepage.html the page going to blank  require(['jquery'], function($){
   $(".opc-block-shipping-information").appendTo($(".opc-wrapper"));
 });
</script>